# Searching past [0]

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

[image: Array and Object]

I can access data in [0] in the photo below with the following node js.

```
const stockxAPI = require('stockx-api');
const stockX = new stockxAPI();

stockX.searchProducts('yeezy', {
    limit: 1
})
.then(products => console.log(products[0]))
.catch(err => console.log(`Error searching: ${err.message}`));
```

but when I try

```
console.log(products[1]))
```

it returns with undefined? why is that and how can I access 0-12. Also is there a way to loop through all [] and pull specific data such as lastSale : 247

Comment: Java? JavaScript? They're two different languages and it is unlikely that your question is about both. Please specify and show your code.

Comment: Ah, `console.log(...)` suggests JavaScript. You may wish to [edit] and improve the question. The [ask] link might help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels node JS I added the simple script above. basically trying to access data in all of the [] but I receive undefined in anything after [0]

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stockx-api#searching-for-products), `limit` is used to restrict the number of results. You are passing the value as 1, which means you are getting only one result and hence `products[1]` is `undefined`. Try the code below:

```
const stockxAPI = require('stockx-api');
const stockX = new stockxAPI();

stockX.searchProducts('yeezy', {
    limit: 12 // increased the value to 12
})
.then(products => console.log(products)) // printing the entire array
.catch(err => console.log(`Error searching: ${err.message}`));
```

Comment: Thank you! you are correct, I thought the Limit only applied to searching for multiple shoe titles. I actually wrote a request module of my own that is pulling all the data I need, and looping through, only hard part is the sizing data returned is out of order i.e ( "6' : 235) ("10.5" : 240) so I need to find a way to reorganize the sizing data in order, which I know a custom sort() will work, but i need to keep the sizing: price data together.

Comment: @N3VO, if the answer worked, upvote and mark it so!